# Filter array with array_walk_recursive but deny specific values

Tags: php, recursion, filter

I am trying to filter an array

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'some_key' => 'some_value',
        'attribute' => [
            'id' => 45,
            'cat_id' => 1
        ],
        'sub' => [
            'id' => 17,
            'some_key' => 'some_value',
            'attribute' => [
                'id' => 47,
                'cat_id' => 17
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'some_key' => 'some_value',
        'sub' => [
            'id' => 19,
            'some_key' => 'some_value',
        ],
    ]
];

$childArray = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, static function($value, $key) use(&$childArray){
    if($key === 'id') {
        $childArray[] = $value;
    }
});
```

This returns me an array of all array-fields having `id` as key.

```
[1,45,17,47,2,19]
```

But there is a small problem, some of the array have an key called `attribute` containing an `id`key field that I dont want to have.

```
[1,17,2,19] //this is what I want
```

Is there a way to say "don't take the id inside attribute" ?

*My current solution, I added a filter before my filter :D*

```
/**
 * @param array  $array
 * @param string $unwanted_key
 */
private function recursive_unset(&$array, $unwanted_key)
{
    unset($array[$unwanted_key]);
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->recursive_unset($value, $unwanted_key);
        }
    }
}
```

but this seems like this is not the best practice ^^

Comment: Difficult to achieve that with _array_walk_recursive_ as it visits only leaf key values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse recursively manually instead of `array_walk_recursive` and avoid all under `attribute` key.

```
<?php

$childArray = [];

function collectIDs($arr,&$childArray){
  foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($key === 'attribute') continue;
    if(is_array($value)) collectIDs($value,$childArray);
    else if($key === 'id') $childArray[] = $value;
  }
}

collectIDs($array,$childArray);
print_r($childArray);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/V6uFf

Answer (score 1):

Find a function that will flatten your array. The result should look like this (I have a class for this):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'some_key' => "some_value",
    'attribute.id' => 45,
    'attribute.cat_id' => 1,
    'sub.id' => 17,
    'sub.some_key' => "some_value",
    'sub.attribute.id' => 47,
    'sub.attribute.cat_id' => 17,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'some_key' => "some_value",
    'sub.id' => 19,
    'sub.some_key' => "some_value",
  ),
)
```

So you have all keys available and can work with a modified array_walk.

```
$childArray = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, static function($value, $key) use(&$childArray){
    $keys = array_reverse(explode(".",$key));
    if($keys[0] === 'id' AND (!isset($keys[1]) OR $keys[1] != 'attribute')) {
        $childArray[] = $value;
    }
});
```

The RecursiveArrayIterator class is also very suitable when array values ​​are to be collected depending on keys and values ​​on different levels.

```
$result = [];
$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($it as $key => $value) {
  $parentLevel = $it->getDepth()-1;
  $parentKey = $it->getSubIterator($parentLevel)->key();
  if($key === 'id' AND $parentKey !== 'attribute'){
    $result[] = $value;
  }
}

var_export($result);
//array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 17, 2 => 2, 3 => 19, )
```

Comment: Idea for this solution is nice, but this would force me to run through the array several times. And thats actually what I want to avoid :) but still +1 for the idea

Comment: Thanks for the praise. Nowadays, writing code that is understandable is more important than saving a microsecond on execution. I've added a variant.

Comment: I love to see that there are always several ways to come to rome :D Using the Iterator is also a good possibility.

Answer (score 1):

To return the qualifying ids instead of creating a reference variable, merge recursive calls of the function as you iterate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ANCRH))

```
function getIds($array) {
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'id') {
            $ids[] = $value;
        } elseif ($key !== 'attribute' && is_array($value)) {
            $ids = array_merge($ids, getIds($value));
        }
    }
    return $ids;
}

var_export(getIds($array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 17,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 19,
)
```